# User Management to access other user's file

Tags: permissions, sudo

Basically I already have user `deploy` that has access to the script to deploy the application.

What I would like is to create new user under `deploy`'s group so that I can access/run the script. If possible I would also like the new user to share the same `home/` dir of user deploy

Comment: Not sure why you would want to share the home dir with the new user, when you can just create a new user with sudo perms and accomplish the same thing. Alas, you should be able to add any new users to the `deploy` group and make sure the /home/deploy perms are set to allow members of the `deploy` have full perms `chmod 770 /home/deploy`

Comment: @hamiheim because when I create new user it will create another group, and home dir. I would like to clarify so based on what you said that create another user  with it's own home dir. If i need to access deploy's files. I need to go to deploy's home dir? is this correct?

Comment: Based on what I said, yeah that's the way you'd do it, however if you REALLY want the two users to share the exact same home directory, you can specify the home directory when you create the new user `sudo useradd myuser -d /home/deploy` but I anticipate you having perms issues still when the deploy user creates files in the shared home directory. You'll still need to probably add the new user to the `deploy` group to make sure you don't run into those issues. Although I could be wrong, I've honestly never deployed anything in that type of scenario.

Comment: Linux directories don't normally inherit permissions by default the way windows directories do, so just because the two users share the same home folder/`rwx` perms in the directory, doesn't mean they share those perms with any files created in the directory by each respective user.